# How can I simulate a limited (256) color palette in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, webgl

On Twitter, I found this screenshot of a game in development:

[image]

The image on top seems to be without any color limitation. But the two other pictures at the bottom have a 256 color palette.

I want to achieve a similar effect in *my* game (I am using OpenGL). How can I do so?

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/43294/creating-a-retro-style-palette-swapping-effect-in-opengl

Comment: Do you want to draw oldschool like 256 color graphics or do you want to make 24bit graphics look like old school graphics? In other words do you want to post process or actually use a 256 color palette? [Here's how to do paletted 256 color graphics in WebGL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695658/emulating-palette-based-graphics-in-webgl-v-s-canvas-2d)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I am the creator of that image.

The image on the right is rendered using a color look-up texture. In the final GLSL shader, I apply the dither, then convert the RGB values into integers in the range 0<=x<40, combine them into a single index, then look up the resulting color value in this image:

[image: color look up table]

The lowest row is the raw palette.

The image to the left is made purely in the shader by downsampling the red and green channels to 8 values, and the blue channel to 4 values after applying the dither, resulting in RGB332. I've also played around with 7 red, 9 green and 4 blue shades, resulting in only 252 colors, but with a bigger emphasis on green, which the human eye is the most sensitive to.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a color grading lookup table in a postprocessing step as described [here](http://codelab.wordpress.com/2012/10/22/simple-color-grading-for-games/) and probably [here](https://www.google.de/search?q=color+grading+lut+opengl).

[image]

After you've implemented this, all you'll have to do is make a screenshot, overlay the lookup texture ontop of it, then edit it in arbitrary graphics software until you like it - and then retrieve the modified lookup texture again. This may or may not include reducing the retrieved lookup table to a subset of colors.

When loading the lookup texture with color limitation in mind, just make sure to disable all filtering, so it won't produce additional colors.