# How can I create a pixellated, limited-palette appearance in modern OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, c++

I wanna get some old art style (256 color, dithering, etc) in modern OpenGL in an effective way. Maybe using a low resolution (320x240) rendered at a bigger space so that the pixels looks "bigger?" I'd just like to fake this old style on modern GPUs.

Comment: Color palettes and upscaling your 320x240 image to your (most likely) 1920x1080 screen can easily be done in a postprocessing shader. A toon shader/cel shader should be a good starting point.

Comment: So you talking about render the scene in a 320x240 buffer and after render like a image in bigger resolution... This would be a opmized way to do in Real time?

Comment: All of your questions have been answered elsewhere, [low resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071090/low-resolution-in-opengl-to-mimic-older-games), [limited colors](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67724/how-can-i-simulate-a-limited-256-color-palette-in-opengl), and although not on an SE site, there's a blog post about [dithering](http://alex-charlton.com/posts/Dithering_on_the_GPU/)

Answer (score 1):

To get pixelated look, you can use OpenGL's framebuffer functionality to render to texture (glFramebufferTexture2D etc.), then draw that texture as a rectangle with nearest-neighbour scaling.

Comment: This answer would greatly benefit from a short example!